# hide before load completed -jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, hide, fade

I have tried this code to hide the body, and show when is loaded in totality. But I noticed that is not working well, because when the fade occurs, some images are not yet loaded.

How I can do this effect?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nav').fadeIn(700);
});
</script>


<body class="nav" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely it's as simple as:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.nav').fadeIn(700);
});
```

Comment: yes, the problem is document, is just change to window. Thanksss

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for the images (questionable idea, but it's your site) you can just handle the "load" event instead:

```
$(document).load(function() { $('.nav').fadeIn(700); });
```

I say that that's a questionable idea because it may take some time to get the images, and that may be confusing. However, I don't have any clue what your site looks like, of course, so perhaps it's fine.

Oh, also: if you're really just targetting the body element, then you can just use

```
$('body').fadeIn(700);
```

Not that it matters at all in this context, but that's going to be more efficient.